# ERROR: [dn3]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-replication, timescaledb, database-cluster

I have been working on the timescaleDB multinode clustering concept. When I go to add a data node, I run the add_data_node query in the access node at that time I got an error like SSL Connection has been closed unexpectedly

Config in the access node

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
enable_partitionwise_aggregate = on
jit = off
```

Config in Data Node

**Postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_prepared_transactions = 150
wal_level = logical
```

If you know the root cause of the problem let me know

Comment: None of the configs you have shared with us seem relevant to the question.  What is the SSL-related config?  What messages are in the log file for both nodes?

Comment: Actually, I have created four clusters in my machine. from that clusters, two data nodes are working well and the clusters ports are 5432, and 5433.  And another two nodes are running in ports 5434, 5435, When I add these node as data  node I got a error

Answer (score 0):

While running the add_data_node query, the connection will be made. if any unexpected error will be thrown from the data_node service. it throws the error with the SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly.

To check the PostgreSQL database error log we need to enable two of the configurations.

```
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
```

Through the log what I have found is, in the postgresql.conf file, 'shared_preload_libraries' was with the empty string. I want to add the string 'timescaldb' for that variable (shared_preload_libraries).

I will not recommend this enabling log for production.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-investigate-postgres-managed-server-error-ssl-connection-has-been-closed-unexpectedly

Comment: Enabling a log will helpful to debug the issue, By doing this we can find the root cause of the issue.